# Proof of compact sets

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $(X, \mathcal{T}_1)$ and $(Y, \mathcal{T}_2)$ topological spaces, let $A \subset X$ and $B \subset Y$ such that $A \times B$ is compact, let $W$ an open set such that $A \times B \subset W$. Prove that there exist $U \in \mathcal{T}_1$ and $V \in \mathcal{T}_2$ such that $A \times B \subset U  \times V \subset W$.

**My idea.** Since $W$ is open in $X \times Y$ then $W= \bigcup_{\alpha \in I} \ (A_\alpha \times B_\alpha)$ where $A_{\alpha} \in \mathcal{T_1}$ and $B_\alpha \in \mathcal{T_2}$, and since $W$ is compact, we have that $$A \times B \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^n \ (A_{\alpha_i} \times B_{\alpha_i})$$
I take $U= \bigcup_{i=1}^{n} A_{\alpha_i}$ and $V= \bigcup_{i=1}^{n} B_{\alpha_i}$, but I'm not sure if $A \times B \subset U  \times V \subset W$.

Comment: You are trying to prove Wallace theorem. Its proof may be found in many general topology's books.

Comment: First use the compactness of $B$ to prove the special case in which $A=\{x\}$ is a single point. Now use the compactnes of $A$ to prove the general case.

Comment: @Tyrone The hypothesis does not say that A and B are compact

Comment: If one of $A,B$ is empty, then $A\times B$ is empty and there is nothing to prove. If both $A$ and $B$ are nonempty, then they are the continuous images of the projections from the compact space $A\times B$, so are themselves compact.